# Why cannot I use the 'view cut' function in Abaqus when I change the 'Countour Intervals'?

Tags: simulation

I'm doing a mechanical analysis with abaqus.I need to print the sectional stress diagram of the workpiece.

In the beginning,I chose the 'Continuous' in 'Countour Intervals' and use the 'view cut' function,then it can display cross-section normally,however it doesn't show the degree of differentiation I need,so I chose the 'Discrete'.The default 'Interval type' is 'Uniform' but it had the same question(As shown in the following picture),so I changed it to log.
[image]

Then, the 'view cut' function lost effectiveness(As shown in the following picture).
[image]

I don't konw why it was and I want to konw how can i fix it or is there another ways to show a highly differentiated diagram.

Thank you for your answer!